Identify movie with manipulative/sociopathic schoolgirl?
I've been trying to find this movie googling various keywords, but found nothing.
Here are all the details I remember of the plot:

the girl is in boarding school of some sort
she (falsely) accuses one of her teachers of sexually harassing her, for revenge of some sort (maybe because she had tried to get with him and he had not returned her affection?)
she gets her innocent friend to testify in court with her about this teacher 
in court, the teacher uses an apology note the protagonist wrote him in detention to show that she was actually coming on to him rather than the other way around. However, the note sounds purely innocent and he realizes it was just the way she had written it.
the protagonist preforms oral sex on a variety of characters to get them to do what she wants

Here are some movies it is not:

Lost and Delirious
Wild Child
Moth Diaries

It's also not a very recent movie... probably 90s.

Pretty Persuasion, a black comedy about a manipulative private school student who falsely accuses her teacher of sexual harassment to get back at him. The seductive apology letter recited innocently in court, the oral services she gives out (to both sexes) and her naive Muslim friend lying in court, it's all there. It's from 2005, though. Here's the trailer.
